# Why are loading bar in VBA created by using UserForms to call the main subroutine instead of the other way round?

Tags: excel, vba, loading, userform, progress

I've read through quite a few tutorials on creating a loading bar or progress bar using UserForms in VBA but all of them guide me in the following steps:

1. Create a button to call the UserForm
2. UserForm calls subroutine
3. Subroutine updates the bar
4. Unload bar within subroutine

Why can't I do the following instead:

1. Create a button to call the subroutine
2. Subroutine calls UserForm
3. Subroutine updates the bar
4. Unload bar within subroutine

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Probably because if you call a UserForm modal (which is default) in your second approach, then the subroutine stops executing until the UserForm is finished and closed. And after that the subroutine proceeds. And if you don't call it modal then the user can work on without having to wait until the subroutine is finished. He can just ignore the UserForm because Excel is not blocked by a modal view. See [Show Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/show-method) for the difference between *modal* and *modeless*.

Comment: @Peh So am I right to say that using a subroutine to call a modeless UserForm is the same as the above method 1? Or is it different? What is the best practice?

Comment: I wrote an answer to explain the differences between the 2 methods. In my opinion it is not a question of best practice it is a question of what you need or which approach is the best for your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to stop you doing it that way.  The code below shows a rough mock-up of the VBA required.

This approach makes it easier to reuse your progress form elsewhere in this, and other, projects.  Just make sure the progress logic, within the subroutine, is separated from the display logic, within the form.

```
' Event fired by a button on the Excel grid.
Sub Example_OnClick()

    Dim myForm As UserForm1     ' Replace with your form here.


    ' Display the form.
    ' Ensure it is not modal, as this would prevent subsequent lines
    ' from executing while the form is open.
    myForm.Show False

    Do Until myForm.Progress = 100

        ' ToDo: Add processing logic here.

        ' Update the progress bar.
        myForm.IncrementPrgress 1
    Loop

    ' Remove the from
    Unload myForm
End Sub
```

Comment: But as I said in my comment above: The disadvantage of doing it this way is that it doesn't force the user to wait until `Example_OnClick` has finished. If this is a long term process let's say 1 minute or more then the user is still able to modify the worksheets during the run time of the procedure (which can break the running process in several cases). A modal UserForm prevents this. So these are just 2 different use cases and you need to decide which one suits best to your application.

Comment: Agree there are pro's and con's.  Without more context it is hard to judge.  If the bar is reporting progress of an external process (perhaps a large file upload) then it might be better if users can continue to edit Excel in meantime.  Suspect form here is used as a substitute for a custom control.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the differences between the 2 methods.

#### Method 1

1. **Create a button to call the UserForm**
   *We load the user form modal (this is default behavior in Excel) so the userform is on top and the user can only interact with that userform but not with Excel sheets anymore until the form is closed.*
2. **UserForm calls subroutine**
   *Only that userform can call the subroutine because of modal mode.*
3. **Subroutine updates the bar**
4. **Unload bar within subroutine**

#### Method 2

1. **Create a button to call the subroutine**
2. **Subroutine calls UserForm**
   *The userform needs to be loaded modeless. Because if you load it modal then the subroutine execution would stop at this point until the form is closed again. If you call it modeless then the subroutine execution proceeds, but the form does not block Excel sheets and the user still can edit sheets while the form is open. It is like having Excel and the form parallel instead of having the form on top of Excel (modal).*
3. **Subroutine updates the bar**
   *The subroutine proceeds because form is modeless. If it was modal the subroutine would have stopped until the form is closed and you could not update the bar anymore*
4. **Unload bar within subroutine**

---

#### So how to decide which method is the best for you?

This depends on wether you want to allow the user to access a worksheet while the progress bar is shown (method 2) or disallow it and keep the form on top of Excel (method 1). This is completely up to you which approach you need.